# "Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency() must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency()"

Tags: 7, drush, composer

I'm using **PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14**, **Drush 8.4.12** (latest), and **Drupal 7.98** (not yet updated).

I'm having a problem with a Drush command which uses Google APIs, Google Auth, and Google services. I get the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency($message, array $context = []) in /home/eliosh/PhpstormProjects/Mega7/sources/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 681
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
> Error: Declaration of Monolog\Logger::emergency(Stringable|string $message, array $context = []): void must be compatible with Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::emergency($message, array $context = []) in
> /home/eliosh/PhpstormProjects/Mega7/sources/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php, line 681

Following [this comment](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/issues/1808#issuecomment-1888663748) in the monolog repo, I've added the following code before the call to the "problematic" function.

```
var_dump(class_exists('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'),
  (new \ReflectionClass('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface'))->getFileName()
);
```

The output is the following

```
bool(false)
string(71) "phar:///usr/local/bin/drush8/vendor/psr/log/Psr/Log/LoggerInterface.php"
```

This is the output of `composer show`.

```
composer/ca-bundle               1.4.0     Lets you find a path to the system CA bundle, and includes a fallback to the Mozilla CA bundle.
dg/twitter-php                   v3.8      Small and easy Twitter library for PHP
domnikl/statsd                   2.10.0    a PHP client for statsd
donatj/simplecalendar            v0.6.2    A light, easy to use calendar rendering library
exads/exads-api-client-php       v1.3.1    Exads API client
fastglass/sendgrid               2.0.6     This library allows you to send emails through SendGrid using PHP and Guzzle 6.x.
firebase/php-jwt                 v6.10.0   A simple library to encode and decode JSON Web Tokens (JWT) in PHP. Should conform to the current spec.
geoip2/geoip2                    v2.13.0   MaxMind GeoIP2 PHP API
giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php   7.7.5     PHP Port of Google's libphonenumber
giggsey/locale                   1.9       Locale functions required by libphonenumber-for-php
google/apiclient                 v2.15.3   Client library for Google APIs
google/apiclient-services        v0.331.0  Client library for Google APIs
google/auth                      v1.34.0   Google Auth Library for PHP
guzzlehttp/guzzle                7.8.1     Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
guzzlehttp/promises              2.0.2     Guzzle promises library
guzzlehttp/psr7                  2.6.2     PSR-7 message implementation that also provides common utility methods
intervention/image               2.7.2     Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration
james-heinrich/getid3            v1.9.23   PHP script that extracts useful information from popular multimedia file formats
jean85/pretty-package-versions   2.0.5     A library to get pretty versions strings of installed dependencies
jenssegers/imagehash             v0.9.0    Perceptual image hashing for PHP
maxmind-db/reader                v1.11.1   MaxMind DB Reader API
maxmind/web-service-common       v0.9.0    Internal MaxMind Web Service API
mongodb/mongodb                  1.11.0    MongoDB driver library
monolog/monolog                  3.5.0     Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
paragonie/constant_time_encoding v2.6.3    Constant-time Implementations of RFC 4648 Encoding (Base-64, Base-32, Base-16)
paragonie/random_compat          v9.99.100 PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phpseclib/phpseclib              3.0.35    PHP Secure Communications Library - Pure-PHP implementations of RSA, AES, SSH2, SFTP, X.509 etc.
psr/cache                        3.0.0     Common interface for caching libraries
psr/http-client                  1.0.3     Common interface for HTTP clients
psr/http-factory                 1.0.2     Common interfaces for PSR-7 HTTP message factories
psr/http-message                 2.0       Common interface for HTTP messages
psr/log                          3.0.0     Common interface for logging libraries
ralouphie/getallheaders          3.0.3     A polyfill for getallheaders.
starkbank/ecdsa                  0.0.4     fast openSSL-compatible implementation of the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)
symfony/deprecation-contracts    v3.4.0    A generic function and convention to trigger deprecation notices
symfony/polyfill-php80           v1.28.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 8.0+ features to lower PHP versions
```

This is the output of `composer show -p`.

```
composer                   2.6.2     Composer package
composer-plugin-api        2.6.0     The Composer Plugin API
composer-runtime-api       2.2.2     The Composer Runtime API
ext-apcu                   5.1.21    The apcu PHP extension
ext-bcmath                 8.1.2     The bcmath PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-calendar               8.1.2     The calendar PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-ctype                  8.1.2     The ctype PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-curl                   8.1.2     The curl PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-date                   8.1.2     The date PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-dom                    20031129  The dom PHP extension
ext-exif                   8.1.2     The exif PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-ffi                    8.1.2     The FFI PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-fileinfo               8.1.2     The fileinfo PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-filter                 8.1.2     The filter PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-ftp                    8.1.2     The ftp PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-gd                     8.1.2     The gd PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-gettext                8.1.2     The gettext PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-gmp                    8.1.2     The gmp PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-hash                   8.1.2     The hash PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-iconv                  8.1.2     The iconv PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-igbinary               3.2.6     The igbinary PHP extension
ext-imagick                3.6.0     The imagick PHP extension
ext-json                   8.1.2     The json PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-libxml                 8.1.2     The libxml PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-mbstring               8.1.2     The mbstring PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-memcached              3.1.5     The memcached PHP extension
ext-mongodb                1.12.0    The mongodb PHP extension
ext-msgpack                2.2.0RC1  The msgpack PHP extension
ext-mysqli                 8.1.2     The mysqli PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-mysqlnd                0         The mysqlnd PHP extension (actual version: mysqlnd 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-openssl                8.1.2     The openssl PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pcntl                  8.1.2     The pcntl PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pcre                   8.1.2     The pcre PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pdo                    8.1.2     The PDO PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pdo_mysql              8.1.2     The pdo_mysql PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pdo_sqlite             8.1.2     The pdo_sqlite PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-pdo_sqlsrv             5.11.0    The pdo_sqlsrv PHP extension
ext-phar                   8.1.2     The Phar PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-phash                  0.9.6     The pHash PHP extension
ext-posix                  8.1.2     The posix PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-readline               8.1.2     The readline PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-redis                  5.3.5     The redis PHP extension
ext-reflection             8.1.2     The Reflection PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-session                8.1.2     The session PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-shmop                  8.1.2     The shmop PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-simplexml              8.1.2     The SimpleXML PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sockets                8.1.2     The sockets PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sodium                 8.1.2     The sodium PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-spl                    8.1.2     The SPL PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sqlite3                8.1.2     The sqlite3 PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sqlsrv                 5.11.0    The sqlsrv PHP extension
ext-sysvmsg                8.1.2     The sysvmsg PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sysvsem                8.1.2     The sysvsem PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-sysvshm                8.1.2     The sysvshm PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-tokenizer              8.1.2     The tokenizer PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-uploadprogress         2.0.2     The uploadprogress PHP extension
ext-xdebug                 3.1.2     The xdebug PHP extension
ext-xml                    8.1.2     The xml PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-xmlreader              8.1.2     The xmlreader PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-xmlwriter              8.1.2     The xmlwriter PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-xsl                    8.1.2     The xsl PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-zend-opcache           8.1.2     The Zend OPcache PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
ext-zip                    1.19.5    The zip PHP extension
ext-zlib                   8.1.2     The zlib PHP extension (actual version: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14)
lib-curl                   7.81.0    The curl library
lib-curl-libssh            0.9.6     curl libssh version
lib-curl-openssl           3.0.2     curl OpenSSL version (3.0.2)
lib-curl-zlib              1.2.11    curl zlib version
lib-date-timelib           2021.11   date timelib version
lib-date-zoneinfo          0         zoneinfo ("Olson") database for date
lib-fileinfo-libmagic      540       fileinfo libmagic version
lib-gd                     2.3.0     The gd library
lib-gmp                    6.2.1     The gmp library
lib-iconv                  2.35      The iconv library
lib-imagick-imagemagick    6.9.11.60 The imagick-imagemagick library
lib-libsodium              1.0.18    The libsodium library
lib-libxml                 2.9.13    libxml library version
lib-libxslt                1.1.34    The libxslt library
lib-libxslt-libxml         2.9.13    libxml version libxslt is compiled against
lib-mbstring-libmbfl       1.3.2     mbstring libmbfl version
lib-mbstring-oniguruma     6.9.7     mbstring oniguruma version
lib-memcached-libmemcached 1.0.18    libmemcached version
lib-mongodb-libbson        1.20.0    libbson version of mongodb
lib-mongodb-libmongoc      1.20.0    libmongoc version of mongodb
lib-openssl                3.0.2     OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
lib-pcre                   10.39     The pcre library
lib-pcre-unicode           14.0.0    PCRE Unicode version support
lib-pdo_sqlite-sqlite      3.37.2    The pdo_sqlite-sqlite library
lib-sqlite3-sqlite         3.37.2    The sqlite3-sqlite library
lib-zip-libzip             1.7.3     The zip-libzip library
lib-zlib                   1.2.11    The zlib library
php                        8.1.2     The PHP interpreter
php-64bit                  8.1.2     The PHP interpreter, 64bit
php-ipv6                   8.1.2     The PHP interpreter, with IPv6 support
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have a conflict with vendor code loaded by PHPStorm, obviously.

Comment: This error happens also outside phpstorm, on the remote server. 
As you can see, the problem is with the implementation of LoggerInterface in drush 8

Comment: As perhaps you can see, Drush is conflicting with `PhpstormProjects/Mega7/sources/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php`.

Comment: @cilefen – I think this is just a folder name, nothing to do with Pstorm. I think this is just a PHP 8.1 compat issue.

Comment: All that's missing is probably just a `: void` after the mentioned function declaration.

Comment: @eliosh – Try to further update monolog or check its issue queue.

Comment: How is Drush installed there? In what way is Composer involved with this question about a Drupal 7 site?

Comment: This is a classic result of running a global Drush where there is another autoloader and conflicting dependencies. You basically can’t do that. Anyway let’s get those details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150937/discussion-between-cilefen-and-leymannx).

Answer (score 1):

Global Drush installs are not supported when the codebase auto loads with Composer and this is the reason. Install and run Drush [as documented](https://www.drush.org/12.x/install/).

Comment: Drush 12 does not work with Drupal 7

Comment: That's well understood. Can you not install Drush 8 via Composer into this site? If not you may be in a situation where vendor dependencies you installed into the codebase, in a PHP 8.1 setting, cannot be installed alongside Drush 8, and you may be forced to look for lower versions of those dependencies.

Comment: You are right. Adding "drush/drush": "<9" to composer.json, downgraded psr/log and monolog to be all compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, with Drupal 7, you don't need to add drush as a requirement via composer.

The solution to this problem is to require drush via composer, but forcing the version "<9", the only compatible with drupal 7.

In this way, composer downgraded "psr/log" and "monolog/monolog" packages and we can continue using global drush 8

Thanks a lot to everyone.